# Error "Method InventMovement.pdsCWRemainPhysical must be overridden"

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012-r3

Retail\Journals\Open statements
while calculating statement in the Retail error is prompting.
"Method InventMovement.pdsCWRemainPhysical must be overridden."
[Statements form error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpmuW.png)

I placed breakpoint and i found a checkmark for CatchWt item InventMovement.pdsCWRemainPhysical()
method should be overridden for Catch wt items.
[checkmark in script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSDj1.png)
Does it mean for Catch wt items there is limitation in Retail module.?
we can't able to post a statement for catch weight items in default application(need to do customization)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at method `updateEstimate` of table `RetailTransactionSalesTrans` (from the stack trace of your second screenshot). There the `InventMovement` object is created. If you take a look at the `construct` method of class `InventMovement` you will see that for retail statements, an instance of class `InventMov_Statement` is created. This is a subclass of `InventMovement` which does not overwrite the `pdsCWRemainPhysical` method, which in turn causes the error you describe.

I'm not familiar enough with the catch weight functionality to answer your question if catch weight items are allowed in the retail module. But at least for the statement calculation there is a gap (and in my view a bug in the standard application).

A customization should be easy, just overwrite method `pdsCWRemainPhysical` (and probably other `pdsCW*` methods) in class `InventMov_Statement`. Of course you first have to define what values these methods should return for retail statements. To do that you might want to compare how these methods are implemented in other subclasses of `InventMovement` (e.g. `InventMov_Sales`). Please make sure to test such a customization for possible side effects.

Comment: Appreciate your time to take a look into this. Indeed i know what you have explained. My Question is about catch wt functionality available in Retail or not?As you know It won't merely workout by overriding method & need to consider lot of things.

Comment: Since this is not a programming question, but a functional question, I was going to suggest that you ask it somewhere else, e.g. in the [AX Community Retail Forum](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33?pi53287=0&category=Retail), but then I noticed that [you already did](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/201208) :)